# .NET ODBC DataProvider never connects via Transoft ODBC driver

Tags: .net, odbc, transoft

I've got a windows service that I've written in .Net.  In our current implementation we are interfacing with a Transoft ODBC.  I've got logging implemented, and basically when we open the ODBC connection it just never connects.  Never errors out or anything.

We've been able to connect to the database via Access, so we know the connectivity works, and the ODBC driver is set up properly.

I can't find a timeout on the actual Connection object, or anything else I might be able to adjust to make the connection work.

```
    Dim ODBCConn As New Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(ConnString)
    ODBCConn.Open()
```

Any thoughts or insights on what might be happening?

Thanks,
Brian Swanson

Comment: Hi Brian did you ever figure this out? I've got the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Try this to connect:

```
OdbcConnection objJAMIS = new OdbcConnection("dsn=" + szDSN);
```

Where szDSN is your DSN as defined in odbc connections.